# Yammer with Python - Retrieving feed

Tags: python, r, yammer

I'm trying to download my yammer feed using Python (actually trying to do it in R but can't figure that out either) and I can't get the yampy module to import. I installed yampy using "python -m pip install yampy" in the command line but when I try to run the import statement I get the following error:

> import yampy
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\yampy__init__.py", line 22, in 
>    from authenticator import Authenticator ImportError: No module named 'authenticator'

Anybody know how what is going on?

Comment: What OS and version of Python do you have? Is it any better if you do pip install yampy at the command prompt instead of python -m pip

Comment: @Evan D'Agostini, I am having the same issue, it looks like its an internal issue with the yampy library, did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, and it is indeed an internal issue with the library: Yampy is written in Python 2, and your project is Python 3. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/yammer/yam-python/issues/22?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container) on the github page that has been open since Feb 2015.

I guess you can try to upgrade the library to Python 3. Good luck!

---

**Update**: Anthony Shaw (tonybaloney on Github) published [a package for Python 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yampy3/1.0) called `yampy3` specifically to address this issue.