# Yampy import error: no module named 'authenticator'

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4, python-import, yammer

**TL;DR**: Yampy uses relative imports... is there some setting I can change that would make it work as-is (without having to refactor every `import` in the project)?

---

Windows 7, Python 3.4.3, PyCharm 2016.1.4, Yampy 1.0

Should be fairly simple question -- hoping someone has encountered this before. I am following the [quickstart guide](http://pythonhosted.org/yampy/quickstart). Someone asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26704593/6519905) a year ago with less information, but there was no answer.

I created a virtualenv, activated, and installed yampy. That gave the import error below, so I uninstalled and installed again:

```
(MyVenv) C:\Users\me>pip install yampy
Collecting yampy
  Using cached yampy-1.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in c:\virtual environments\myvenv\lib\site-packages (from yampy)
Installing collected packages: yampy
  Running setup.py install for yampy ... done
Successfully installed yampy-1.0
```

That created the following directory:

- C:\Virtual Environments\MyVenv\Lib\site-packages\yampy

  - __pycache_ _ (contains appropriate .pyc files)
  - apis

    - __pycache_ _ (contains appropriate .pyc files)
    - __init_ _.py
    - messages.py
    - users.py
    - utils.py
  - __init_ _.py
  - authenticator.py
  - client.py
  - constants.py
  - errors.py
  - models.py
  - yammer.py

Contents of __init_ _.py:

```
"""
The official Python client for Yammer's API
"""

from authenticator import Authenticator
from client import Client
from yammer import Yammer
```

**The issue**:

When I `import yampy` from the python shell, I get the following traceback (this was from PyCharm shell, but same issue in command-line shell):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Virtual Environments\myvenv\lib\site-packages\yampy\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from authenticator import Authenticator
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2016.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
```

That doesn't make any sense to me since everything seems to be there. Thanks!

---

**Update**:

If I change the _init _ file to use absolute imports (`from yampy.authenticator import ..` instead of `from authenticator import..`), it solves the immediate issue, but creates a string of import errors throughout the project. Is there some setting I can change that would require a minimum of refactoring?

Comment: Shout out to @brian-lyttle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should have checked GitHub first: there is an [open issue](https://github.com/yammer/yam-python/issues/22?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container) about this that has been open since Feb 2015. Apparently the project is in Python 2. Going to try forking and updating to Python 3..

---

**Update**: made the changes manually, took about 5 minutes. Imports now!

---

**Better Update**: Anthony Shaw (tonybaloney on Github) published [a package for Python 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yampy3/1.0) called `yampy3`.